# How to install skype with no admins rights?

Tags: windows-7, skype

I remember it was possible for me to install skype with a non admin user on windows XP. Now the school upgraded the system to windows 7 and it tells me I dont have admins rights. I choose an install path to my network drive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your easiest option would be to run Skype from a USB thumb drive using [Skype Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/skype_portable). Saves installing it and also, your logs will be kept on the thumb drive, not on the system, which is a plus.